# Following keras distributed training guide only one gpu is utilized

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**I want to train a network using multiple gpus( 2x NVIDIA RTX A6000 ), on a windows 11 machine.**

I tried copying the Multi-GPU and distributed training code from https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/

However i see that GPU 0 is utilized just fine, but the GPU 1 is only utilized a little bit.

Here is a picture of the utilization:
[GPUs utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3MNh.png)

While using the

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
for gpu_instance in physical_devices: 
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu_instance, True)
```

I can even see huge gaps in the utiliation of GPU 1 as seen in:
[GPUs utliziation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwyXy.png) .
Meaning for several epochs the second gpu was not utilized ***at all***.

The only difference between the code in the example and my code is that I set epochs to 20, and I use:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())
```

Since running without HierarchicalCopyAllReduce() results in an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'NcclAllReduce' used by {{node Adam/NcclAllReduce}} with these attrs: [reduction="sum", shared_name="c1", T=DT_FLOAT, num_devices=2]
Registered devices: [CPU, GPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>
```

***Increasing batch size to 512 seems to help a lot and second gpu is utilized.***[GPUs utilization using 512 batch size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clMMu.png)

I also tried running the code with , strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset again with 512 batch size since this batch size utilized both GPUs well, however doing so makes the second gpu be not used as seen in picture below

```
# Train the model on all available devices.
train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()
train_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)
val_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(val_dataset)
test_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(test_dataset)

#model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20, validation_data=val_dataset)
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20, validation_data=val_dataset, steps_per_epoch=98, validation_steps=98)
```

And again i see that the gpu utilization vanished [GPUs utilization using experimental_distribute_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR7wS.png)

**My question is:**

Why is the second GPU hardly utilized, isn't the batch split between the GPUs equally, ie if batch size is 128 one gpu receives 64 and the other gpu also 64? I assumed that the same model is run on both gpus and they both get half the batch to process, after which the reduce happens.

If the batch was split the same way wouldn't both gpus be similarly utilized even with small batch size?

Also why does distributing dataset using the strategy make utilization worse?